# React Native—react-native-dotenv error: api.addExternalDependency is not a function

Tags: react-native, expo, environment-variables

I am using Expo (version: ~47.0.12) with React Native (version: 0.70.5), and I am unable to use the `react-native-dotenv` npm package. I have followed many tutorials, and they all result in this same error message:

```
./node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js
TypeError: [BABEL] /Users/jessicagallagher/projects/sfl/sfl-mobile/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js: api.addExternalDependency is not a function (While processing: "/Users/jessicagallagher/projects/sfl/sfl-mobile/node_modules/react-native-dotenv/index.js")
```

The tutorials that I have used are basically blogs stating the same information from the [docs](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv).

This is my `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(false);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['module:react-native-dotenv'],
  };
};
```

I have also tried this in my `babel.config.js` file:

```
"plugins": [
    ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
      "moduleName": "@env",
      "path": ".env",
      "blocklist": null,
      "allowlist": null,
      "safe": false,
      "allowUndefined": true,
    }]
  ]
```

My `.env` file is the standard `.env`:

```
API_KEY='12345'
```

Here is my import statement to access the variable:

```
import { API_KEY } from '@env';
```

Normally in VS Code, when I start typing `import { Something } from '`, I will normally get suggestions from packages I have installed. That does not happen here when using `@env`—the suggestion does, however, show up when I import from `'react-native-dotenv'`, but I still get that same error message.

I've read a ton of GitHub issues and am just spinning my wheels at this point.

Comment: point me a comment if it won't work

Comment: @KishanDharajiya It unfortunately didn't work—I am still getting the same error. I also tried clearing my cache. Just to confirm, my babel.config.js file should still contain plugins: ['module:react-native-dotenv'], right?

Comment: do not make any changes into babel.config.js file insted you have to create .babelrc file and add my given code into it

Comment: lets give a try again and point me what happened

Comment: Hi @KishanDharajiya—I followed the steps exactly. I double checked that I am using the same library as you and created the .babelrc file and copied and pasted what you sent below. I've been restarting my server over and over and also making sure that my cache is cleared and doing hard reloads on the browser. I'm still getting that same exact error message. As a matter of fact, nothing on the page even loads even though I commented out import { API_KEY } from '@env' (I get the same error when that import statement is not commented out as well).

Answer (score 0):

Im using This [Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv)

Your Entire Steps is okay you just Missed to create **.babelrc** file

Dont change anything in your **babel.config.js** file,leave it as its

```js
//.babelrc

{
    "plugins": [
      ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
        "envName": "APP_ENV",
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
        "blocklist": null,
        "allowlist": null,
        "verbose": false
      }]
    ]
  }
```

once Entire steps is done try to reload server and boom you will see magic>>

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found a solution here:
https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/377#issuecomment-1309452448

In your package.json, add

```
"resolutions": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
  "babel-loader": "^8.3.0"
}
```

if you are using yarn and

```
"overrides": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
  "babel-loader": "^8.3.0"
}
```

if you are using npm. I also had to use

```
api.cache(false);
```

in my babel.config.js as per the react-native-dotenv docs.
There are also other solutions in the linked issue that may be better.

Comment: That was one of the fixes that I tried as well, and even using Kishan's suggestions above in addition to this fix, I'm still getting that error message.